Which one Dirichlet Theorem refers to arising from a theorem about least character non-residues.
I am learning the Chapter 13 "Least character non-residues $\chi(n)$ and $L(\frac{1}{2}+it, \chi)$" of the book "Topics in Multipliactive Number Theory" written by Montgomery in 1986.
I don't understand Dirichlet Theorem refers to which one, arising from the proof of the follwing theorem.
Theorem
If the Riemann hypothesis is valid then
\begin{equation}\label{eq:S(t)}
  S(t) = \Omega\left((\log t)^{\frac{1}{2}}(\log \log t)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\right),
 \end{equation}
where
$$
  S(t, \chi) = \frac{1}{\pi} \arg L(\frac{1}{2} + it, \chi).
$$
The proof of Theorem
Similar to the proof of Theorem1, for the Riemann zeta function $\zeta(s)$, we have
\begin{align*}
        \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \Lambda(n) n^{-it} \left(e^{-\frac{n}{2x}} - e^{-\frac{n}{x}}\right) &= \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{2-i\infty}^{2+i\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\Lambda(n)}{n^{w+it}}  \left( \left(2x\right)^{w} - \left(x\right)^{w}\right) \Gamma(w) ~\mathrm{d}w\\
        &= \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{2-i\infty}^{2+i\infty} -\frac{\zeta'}{\zeta}(w+it) \left( \left(2x\right)^{w} - \left(x\right)^{w}\right) \Gamma(w) ~\mathrm{d}w\\
        &= -\sum_{\rho} \left( \left(2x\right)^{\rho - it} - \left(x\right)^{\rho - it}\right) \Gamma(\rho - it) + \left(\left(2x\right)^{1 - it} - \left(x\right)^{1 - it}\right) \Gamma(1-it) +O\left(1\right).
\end{align*}
except that there is an additional term on the right, due to the pole of $\zeta(s)$ at $s=1$. From one lemma, It is not provided here with $q=1$, we have
$$
    \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \Lambda(n) n^{-it} \left(e^{-\frac{n}{2x}} - e^{-\frac{n}{x}}\right) \ll x^{\frac{1}{2}} (\log x) \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left|S(u+t)\right| e^{-|u|} \mathrm{d} u + x e^{-|t|}.
$$
By Dirichlet's theorem, we see that for any large $T$, there is a $t$ for which $T^{\frac{1}{2}} \leq t \leq T$ and $\left|n^{-it}-1\right| \leq \frac{1}{2}$ for all $n \leq N = c(\log T)(\log \log T)$ for which $\Lambda(n) \neq 0$, provided that $c$ is sufficently small positive constant. We take $x=\frac{N}{16}$. Then
$$
   \left|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \Lambda(n) n^{-it} \left(e^{-\frac{n}{2x}} - e^{-\frac{n}{x}}\right)\right| \gg x,
$$
so
$$
    \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left|S(u+t)\right| e^{-|u|} \mathrm{d} u \gg (\log t)^{\frac{1}{2}}(\log \log t)^{-\frac{1}{2}},
$$
which we get the desired result.
